# Каким образом ЦПУ считывает по 32 бита из ОЗУ

Tags: память, процессор

Оперативная память состоит из ячеек, который объединены в группы по 8 бит, и каждая такая группа имеет свой уникальный адрес, по которому к ней можно обратиться.

Это значит, что указав адрес ячейки, мы получим 8 бит информации.
Но каким образом процессор, указывая адрес ячейки, получает не 8 бит, а например 32?
Ведь для этого нужно прочесть 4 групп, т.е. указать 4 смежных адреса и прочесть их по очереди?

Comment: В формате самой машинной команды есть указание на то, сколько последовательных байт надо прочесть из памяти за один раз. Во многих процессорах обычно можно прочесть 1, 2, 4 или 8 байт

Comment: Реально процессор за один раз читает гораздо больше. Обычно сразу заполняет целую кеш-линию, которая у современных процессоров x86 - 64 байта, т.е. 512 бит. А для исполнения команды берет из кеша столько байт, сколько требует команда. Чтение отдельных байтов модули памяти на сколько я знаю вообще не поддерживают

Comment: Один байт это минимальная величина адресуемой памяти. Это не значит что за раз считывает один байт.

Comment: Еще все зависит от самой памяти. Если я не ошибаюсь, DDR3, например, не позволяет читать менее 64 бит за раз.

Comment: когда мы указываем адрес памяти, то это адрес какой-то одной конкретной ячейки размером 8 бит. Т.е. RAM на адресный вход попадает адрес, и на выходе - значение по этому адресу. А это только 8 бит. Это устройство RAM

Comment: @ТимурБаймагамбетов Нет, это не так. http://microsin.net/adminstuff/hardware/general-ddr-sdram-functionality.html DDR в минимальном пакете за одну операцию чтения отдает 2 слова данных (4 байта), но пакет может быть и большего размера ...

Comment: А вообще это все не имеет никакого значения. Есть модуль (который у современных процессоров прямо на кристалле самого процессора) как контроллер памяти. С памятью работает он. причем совершенно не зависимо от исполняемой команды. Например современные x86 заранее просматривают очередь команд, которые скорее всего будут выполнены и заказывает у контроллера памяти подгрузить в кеш нужные данные. Контроллер памяти выдаст столько операций чтения, сколько сочтет нужным. А команда в любом случае возьмет то что будет в кеше, того размера сколько ей надо.